# Trying to move AD user and disable the account running some PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to run some PowerShell to move users to different OU and disable the account.

Here is my code

```
    $ADUsers = Import-Xlsx 'C:\User Creation\ADUsersRemoval.xlsx' | Foreach {
        $test = Get-ADUser -LdapFilter "samaccountname -eq '$("$Firstname.$Lastname")" |
                Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Users,OU=Graveyard,DC=domain,DC=dc" -PassThru |
                Disable-ADAccount
    }
}
```

The code runs without errors but doesn't do anything to the user account. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I realized I missed adding the values for `$Firstname` and `$Lastname`.

Here is a code I tested with.

```
    $ADUsers = Import-Xlsx 'C:\User Creation\ADUsersRemoval.xlsx'

    foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
        $Firstname = $User.Firstname
        $Lastname = $User.Lastname

        Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$("$Firstname.$Lastname")'" -Properties 'mail'
    }
}
```

Now works absolutely fine, gives me the details below. clearly reading from my xlsx file ps. Doing it with `'$("$Firstname.$Lastname")'"` works fine. Any other way then it won't read the xlsx file.

```
PSComputerName    : server
RunspaceId        : ****************************************
DistinguishedName : CN=user65 test65,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : user65
mail              : user65.test65@domain.com
Name              : user65 test65
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : afc3fc3b-c43a-4e1b-ad83-804ee605eb00
SamAccountName    : user65.test65
SID               :*************************************
Surname           : test65
UserPrincipalName : user65.test65@domain.com
```

but when trying to do the task of moving user and disabling. it doesn't action

```
$ADUsers = Import-Xlsx 'C:\User Creation\ADUsersRemoval.xlsx'

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
    $Firstname = $User.Firstname
    $Lastname = $User.Lastname

    Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$("$Firstname.$Lastname")'" |
        Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Users,OU=Graveyard,DC=domain,DC=com" -PassThru |
        Disable-ADAccount
}
```

Comment: You should switch to `-filter` instead of `-ldapfilter` since you have the syntax for `-filter` already. You also have an opening single quote without a closing single quote. I would try `Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$("$Firstname.$Lastname")'"`

Comment: `'$("$Firstname.$Lastname")'` should probably be `'${Firstname}.${Lastname}'`. Why do people feel the need to put everything into subexpressions?

Comment: No idea. Even `"userprincipalname -eq '$Firstname.$Lastname'"` would work in most cases.

Comment: [1] where are `'$("$Firstname.$Lastname")"` coming from? that looks like it should be `$_.FirstName` or whatever is in your CSV import. [2] will anything at all be in $Test`? from what i can tell, `Disable-ADAccount` has no output unless you add `-PassThru` to its parameters.

Comment: @AdminOfThings tried that but getting same result

Comment: @Kidbuu For one thing the code snippet you posted has a spurious trailing curly bracket. Also, as others have pointed out, `$Firstname` and `$Lastname` are undefined, and your code uses the parameter `-LdapFilter` with a value for the parameter `-Filter`. Please create a [mcve], test-run *that* code to make sure it still exposes the problem you're trying to debug, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code along with sample input and all errors thrown by it.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers get same result

Comment: @Kidbuu - "get the same result" is NOT what `Ansgar Wiechers` asked you to do. PLEASE, post the code that actually runs and give the errors it produces.

Comment: Also, are you quite sure the users `SamAccountName` has the form of `FirstName.LastName` ?

Comment: Sorry @Lee_Dailey I didn't see the message till after

Comment: It is very rare that a domain would hold unique samaccountname values based off just firstname and lastname. Usually duplicate names are handled by adding a trailing sequence of numbers from 1 to n like User.Test1, User.Test2 and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get it working. I think it was only missing the Values. I'm sure I tried with them in a few times. Thanks for those that helped :)

```
Import-Module activedirectory
Install-module PSExcel

Get-command -module psexcel

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-XLSX 'C:\User Creation\ADUsersRemoval.xlsx'

Foreach ($User in $ADUsers){

$Firstname = $User.Firstname
$Lastname = $User.Lastname

Get-ADUser -filter "samaccountname -eq '$("$Firstname.$Lastname")'"| Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Users,OU=Graveyard,DC=Domain,DC=com" -PassThru | Disable-ADAccount}}
```

Comment: Just one last thing. If i wanted to clear the users Properties e.g description, how would i go about doing this ```|set-ADuser -Description ""```

Comment: You could do that after your `Get-ADUser`. `Get-ADUser .... | Set-ADUser -Description "" -passthru | Move-ADObject ...`

Comment: @AdminOfThings I've sorted it. You have to use ```Set-ADuser -Clear @('Description')```